# How to build readable urls when filters are applied using Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have an web site ([textnook](https://www.textnook.com)) where users can filter books by author name , publisher , etc. On applying filters earlier I was using javascript to build the url and render the request and it looked something like `/book/search/?author_id=1` Can I use angular 2 route to make the url readable while passing the parameters. Is it possible do it like a single page application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use angular 2 route to make the url readable while passing the parameters. Is it possible do it like a single page application?

Yes. `?author_id` can be configured as a *query parameter* : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

From the link it will need to be `;` and not `&`/`?`:

[image]

Comment: the thing is it wont be just i parameter it may be several parameter appended together like `?author_id=1&publisher_id=1` like this it can be several parameters so how do I implement it for that and how to construct the url accordingly?

Comment: Updated the answer. You need `;`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, that is what Angular the router are for. Single Page Application with readable bookmarkable URLs.

You can either encode parameters as "directory" or as query parameter.